# ASP.NET Web API2, one route returns JSON regardless of Accept setting

Tags: asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

This is super weird. I have 3 types of jobs, each with their own routh that starts the work and their own route to get the result. But the code to return the generated object is the same for all three types of job.

For two of the job types the "conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");" works fine. I have one client setting it to JSON and it gets JSON, the other sets it to XML and gets XML. But for the third job type, it always comes back as JSON.

The controller:

```
[Route("v1/reports/{guid}")]
[Route("v2/document/{guid}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string guid)
{
    IHttpActionResult result = CheckForReport(guid, RepositoryStatus.REQUEST_TYPE.DocGen, true);
    if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
        Log.Debug($"Document Get({guid}) = {result}");
    return result;
}
```

The code returning:

```
protected IHttpActionResult CheckForReport(string guid, RepositoryStatus.REQUEST_TYPE requestType, bool returnReport)
{
        switch (reportStatus.RequestType)
        {
            // returns JSON or XML
            case RepositoryStatus.REQUEST_TYPE.TagTree:
                return Ok(Repository.GetTagTree(guid));
            // returns JSON or XML
            case RepositoryStatus.REQUEST_TYPE.Metrics:
                return Ok(Repository.GetMetrics(guid));
            // returns JSON regardless of Accept setting
            case RepositoryStatus.REQUEST_TYPE.DocGen:
                return Ok(Repository.GetReport(guid));
            default:
                return NotFound();
        }
}
```

The object being returned:

```
Document GetReport(string guid);
```

The object itself:

```
[DataContract]
public class Document
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier for this request.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public byte[][] Pages { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing different about the Document object is it has a member that's "byte[][]".

So why is it forcing a JSON return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. In the returned class there's a member object of another class. That class does not have a parameterless constructor. The JSON serializer handles that fine. The XML one does not and apparently in that case ASP.NET figures better to return JSON that throw an exception.

Added the parameterless constructor and now it works fine.